Python script runs fine in Spyder, throws `ModuleNotFoundError` running via command line
I've written a python script that relies on libraries I've created myself.  I've created an __init__.py file in the respective directories to designate them as package directories.
Tree structure looks like this:
/main
  /sub1
  /sub2
  ...

The script itself sits in directory sub1, while the library I'm importing sits in sub2.
Running within Spyder IDE with /main set as home directory, the below import works without issue:
from sub2 import my_handler as mdh

But the same (running from /main using python ./sub1/my_processing.py) throws the below error running via linux command line:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sub2'

I'm guessing this is somehow related to PATH designations but the two sets appear the same (calling sys.path after importing returns the same 7 directories in each case).  What could be causing this?

If you run python on the command line with a subdirectory like python subdir/script.py, it uses that subdirectory as the default module search path.  So in your example, even though main is the current directory, that doesn't matter, because you ran the code with python sub1/my_processing.py, therefore sub1 is treated as the default module search path.

@JohnGordon, so what's the remedy then?  Have never been able to successfully import packages across directories (eg, from ..sub1.my_handler)

The same question here and here
